# Deploy/run the app from Jenkins pipeline with agent docker

Tags: docker, deployment, jenkins-pipeline, dockerfile, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I'm trying to have a sample pipeline (using declarative) which builds/tests/ and deploys a sample (node) app.

I'm using `agent docker` which runs the job in a container ... config and test phases are working fine :

```
pipeline {
  agent {
    docker { image 'node:latest' }
  }
  stages {
    stage('config') {
      steps {
        sh 'npm install'
      }
    }
    stage('run test') {
      steps {
        sh 'npm test'
      }
    }

  }
```

the problem is how to add the `deployment` stage essentially builds a docker image and runs it like :

```
docker build -t myapp .
docker run -d myapp
```

(let's assume this is the way I wanna deploy/run the app ... and have a Dockerfile)

the problem is how to deploy the sample app (use the docker commands) ... adding `deploy` stage here won't work since I'm using the `docker agent` (I guess it's running docker inside docker which sounds wrong!)

Should I kick off a new job - after pipeline succeeds - which uses `agent any` which runs the deployment commands? or there's a better way for running the app?

Answer (score 1):

Docker inside docker is not wrong if made right! 
You can mount parent socket on container node:

```
/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

In Jenkins, Go to `Manage` -> `Configure System` -> scroll to `Cloud` -> click on `Docker Agent templates` -> `Container settings...`.

you will see something like the picture below:

[image]

Use an image like this for agent:

```
FROM jenkins/jnlp-slave
USER root
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y  install \
                   apt-transport-https \
                   ca-certificates \
                   curl \
                   gnupg2 \
                   software-properties-common
RUN curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/gpg | apt-key add -
RUN add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch stable"
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y  install \
               docker-ce \
               docker-ce-cli \
               containerd.io
```

And to execute the docker within the job use:

```
withDockerContainer(image: IMAGE_NAME)
{
    ...
}
```

useful links:

https://adamcod.es/2017/08/19/docker-patterns-socket-mount.html
https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#examples